# React: this is null in event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I have a LoginForm component. I want to check before submit, that both `loginName` and `password` is set. I tried with this code (a lot of stuff omitted):

```
class LoginForm extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      error: "",

      loginName: "",
      password: "",
      remember: true
    };
  }


  submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!this.state.loginName || !this.state.password) { //this is null
      this.setState({ error: "Fill in both fields" });
    } else {
      console.log("submitting form");
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <form className="login" onSubmit={this.submit}>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

however, i get a `TypeError` in the event handler, saying that `this` is null.

What should I be doing?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You need set `this` for `submit` method because now `this` is `undefined`, for this operation you can use `.bind`

```
onSubmit={ this.submit.bind(this) }
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/20407/)

or you can use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
onSubmit={ (e) => this.submit(e) }
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/31122/)

Comment: I've rewritten onSubmit as you suggested and it's working, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

React was binding callbacks to this for you before. But now it is gone, and you have to bind it yourself or make wrapper like

```
onSubmit={() => this.submit()}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have not bound the `this` to your class; You can use ES6 class properties feature to get around the problem in the cleanest way; So all you need to do is:

```
   submit = (e) => {
      // some code here
   }
```

The arrow function will auto bind it; Much nicer than binding it in a constructor; the most important thing is never ever do it this way:

```
onSubmit={() => this.submit()}
```

This will create a function which is an object in javascript and it will take some memory and is now residing inside your redner function! which makes it so expensive. `render` function is part of the code that runs so many times and each time your `submit` function is also created and you will end up with some performance relates issues. So your code should be like:

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
  submit = (e) => {
    // some code here
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <form className="login" onSubmit={ this.submit }>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
        </form>
      );
    }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

Here you will not have the performance issue, also you will not have the binding issue and your code looks much nicer.

Answer (score 2):

For those who is using Babel, you can use [bind operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator) with [transform-function-bind](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-function-bind/) plugin:

```
onSubmit={::this.submit}
```

which is a syntactic sugar for:

```
onSubmit={this.submit.bind(this)}
```