# Missing this in onSubmit event handler with redux-form 6

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am trying to use my componenet props to call an action in submit event handler with redux-form 6.1.1 but in the event handler function I get `"this" is undefined`. here is what I do:

```
class ForgetPasswordForm extends Component {
  xubmit (values) {
    console.log(this);
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(this.xubmit) }>
      ...
    );
  };
}
```

I also tried `() => handleSubmit(this.xubmit.bind(this))` and `this.xubmit.bind(this)` as mentioned in [React: this is null in event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631482/react-this-is-null-in-event-handler) but none of them worked out.

Here is more details about my setup:

- boilerplate: create-react-app v.0.5
- react: v.15.3.2
- redux: v.3.6

Answer (score 1):

`handleSubmit.bind(this.xubmit)` by this way inside the `handleSubmit`, `this` points to `this.xubmit`.

I also suggest you to [read how bind works.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

*Note: I know only JavaScript*

Comment: is it inside the `xubmit`? or in `render`?

Comment: In the "xubmit", that's my event handler function

Comment: where is `handleSubmit` defined? and while consoling,include the name of method where its logging.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide your `handleClick` function I can only imagine that you have directly called the function passed in like `handleClick (fn) { fn() }` and this way you would have access to the context in that `fn`. Also you should pass a function to event handlers. Do something like this and see if it works:

`onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit.bind(this.props.context, this.xubmit.bind(this))}`

You need to send parent component's context to your `ForgetPasswordForm` and bind `handleSubmit` to it to have access to that parent component's context and bind `this.xubmit` to `this` in order for it not to be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

your custom submit function basically is wrong , just edit your code this way.

```
class ForgetPasswordForm extends Component {
 xubmit = (values) => {
  console.log(this);
 }

}
```

an call it this way ,

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit((values) => this.xubmit(values)) }>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use [class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) and arrow function together

class properties is part of [stage-2](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/)

```
class ForgetPasswordForm extends Component {
  xubmit = (values) => {
    console.log(this);
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(this.xubmit) }>;
  };
}
```

Arrow function bind `this` to function