# Using web3modal in class component shows state error

Tags: reactjs, web3js, web3modal

I am using web3modal with walletconnect and portis with the following configuration:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
 import Web3Modal from "web3modal";
 import Portis from "@portis/web3";
 import WalletConnectProvider from "@walletconnect/web3-provider";

 class App extends Component{
  async getData(){
    const  providerOptions={
            injected:{
              display:{
             name: "Injected",
             description: "Connect with the provider in your Browser"
           },
           package:null
            },
           
            walletconnect:{
              package:WalletConnectProvider,
              options:{
                infuraId:"INFURA_ID"
              }
            },
          
            portis:{
     package:Portis,
     options:{
       id:"PORTIS_ID"
     }
            }
          }
      

     const web3Modal = new Web3Modal({
      network: "mainnet", // optional
      cacheProvider: true, // optional
      providerOptions // required
    });
     const provider = await web3Modal.connect();
  const web3=new Web3(provider)
  const accounts= await web3.eth.getAccounts()
  console.log(accounts)
  this.setState({account:accounts[0]})
      const networkId =  await web3.eth.net.getId()
      const mainNetwork =1
  
  const ethBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(this.state.account) / 10 ** 18
  this.setState({ ethBalance })
  
  provider.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {
    this.setState({address:accounts[0]})
    window.location.reload();
  })
  
  provider.on('chainChanged', function (networkId) {
    window.location.reload();
  })
  provider.on("disconnect",function() {
   provider.close();
   web3Modal.clearCachedProvider();
   provider=null;
  });
}
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    account: '',
    ethBalance:'0',
}
```

}
render(){
return(
Get tokens
)}
}

When I am connecting on mobile, it shows a popup window from where I cam choose the provider. When I'm trying to connect on desktop, nothing pops up and it throws an error on retrieving the balance from the current account "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined":

```
const ethBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(this.state.account) / 10 ** 18
this.setState({ ethBalance })
```

How can I get the balance of the current account with web3modal in a class component?

Comment: Your code is weirdly formatted, and at the moment your `constructor` method is missing a closing `}`, so the `render` method isn't defined properly. Basically the code as you've presented it here won't run. It might help just to reformat it so the indentation is correct at least, before doing anything else. Then look into why `this` isn't what you think it is inside the `getData` method.

Comment: @ChrisLear yes, you are right. I'm sorry for the snippet but it's just a demo of the code section that doesn't work,I didn't think it was necessary to copy-paste everything. I modified the code to retrieve the current account  and show it in browser console and it works, however it shows an error for this line of code: `  this.setState({account:accounts[0]})`  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined".  Why would it throw this error if it actually retrieves the account?

Comment: Apparently when I pass  the method to " async ComponentWillMount()" it doesn't throw an error anymore and everything works properly, but that would just trigger it at page load which is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `this` variable is missing when you need it, because you're calling a function that establishes a new `this` variable in its scope.

Try changing

```
async getData() { ...}
```

to

```
const getData = async () {...}
```

I got the idea from [React: this is null in event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631482/react-this-is-null-in-event-handler), and you can read more there. The highest-scoring answer to that question takes a different approach (actually two different approaches), but I think this is better (from a different answer).

The difference is that arrow functions basically leave `this` alone when they run. The precise explanation is long (https://web.archive.org/web/20160625172303/http://blog.getify.com/arrow-this/), and maybe you don't need to read it all.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've tried your method and it works, thank you. I've also managed to do it by binding the method in the constructor `this.loadData=this.loadData.bind(this)`. I don't know which one of them is better to use, but both of them work.

Comment: I think the way I chose is better, which is why I chose it. It's a bit simpler, doesn't require a `'bind'`, and feels cleaner. Also I quite like arrow functions and if I don't need `this` they are mostly just better.

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed response and your help!